# How to add foreign keys in a compact database in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

If I create a SQL Express database via VS2010, I can create diagrams and this way set foreign key relationships. What's the case in a compact database? There is no such option in Server Explorer for this type of DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. In **Server Explorer**, right click the table, select **Table Properties**, and use **Add Relations** view. Remember to press the "Add Relation" button to actually add the releation

Comment: This works in VS2012 as well. Way easier than crafting alter table statements to add FK's.

Answer (score 0):

[Walkthrough: Creating a SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546200%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

To create a relationship between the tables created in the previous procedure

1. In Server Explorer/Database Explorer, expand Tables.
2. Right-click the Orders table and then click Table Properties.
3. Click Add Relations.
4. Type FK_Orders_Customers in the Relation Name box.
5. Select CustomerID in the Foreign Key Table Column list.
6. Click Add Columns.
7. Click Add Relation.
8. Click OK to complete the process and create the relationship in the
   database.
9. Click OK again to close the Table Properties dialog box.